# Why does Flutter web sometimes not launch?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-web

I set up my Flutter on the master channel for web development with Chrome and when I go to launch it, sometimes it's opening chrome at http://localhost:8080/ with the browser showing `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, other times it's opening something like http://localhost:51043/#/, the debug console actually starts outputting and the app loads. There doesn't seem to be any obvious factor influencing this behavior, but I would like to get it to run every time, if possible.

Here's how the good doctor is looking:

```
    [√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.21.0-6.0.pre.150, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.900], locale en-US)
    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    [√] Chrome - develop for the web
    [√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    [√] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
    [√] Connected device (2 available)
```

And here's my launch.json:

```
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "type": "pwa-chrome",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
                "url": "http://localhost:8080",
                "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Could it be that something else (even an old instance) is already running on localhost:8080?

Comment: @nvoigt It could be, but it isn't

Comment: Do you use an IDE? How do you launch?

Comment: vscode with flutter extension

Comment: delete that launch.json

Answer (score 4):

@DeanVillamia 's comment fixed the issue for me in Visual Studio, posting a answer to make it more visible. After updating many files in my project and integrating Firebase I could no longer launch. I deleted `launch.json` then my project launched normally.

Comment: saved the night!